# What's the difference between these two scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know what's the difference between these two scripts, The output looks similar!

---

```
def test(a,b,c,*args):
    print (a,b,c)
    for n in args: print(n, end=' ')

 test('aa','bb','cc',1,2,3,4)
```

Output:
    aa bb cc
    1 2 3 4

---

```
def test(a,b,c,*args):
    print (a,b,c)
    print (*args)
```

Output:

```
aa bb cc  
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of them prints each value separately, in a loop, but tells the `print()` function to print a space after each value instead of a newline.

The second version prints all values in *one* go, with spaces in between and a newline at the end. Each value in `args` is passed to the `print()` function as separate arguments, as if you issued the expression `print(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3])` instead.

There is thus a difference. The first version prints:

```
1<space>2<space>3<space>4<space>
```

while the second version prints:

```
1<space>2<space>3<space>4<newline>
```